# Deploy asp.net core website or console app using Visual Studio for Mac

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.0, visual-studio-mac

I've found instructions for deploying directly to Azure, but not a lot for deploying to just a local folder.  There doesn't seem to be anything under the menus or add-ons that seemed to do it either.  Maybe it's a command line tool?

Comment: where do you want to deploy ? local folder in your mac  ?

Comment: @Shyju Yes, local folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer, or at least an answer.  I couldn't find any way to publish from within Visual Studio for Mac, but just using the command line I was able to do it.

This is the website I found the answer on: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish?tabs=netcore2x

This was the commands I found in case that site goes down.

```
dotnet publish [<PROJECT>] [-c|--configuration] [-f|--framework] [--force] [--manifest] [no-dependencies] [--no-restore] [-o|--output] [-r|--runtime] [--self-contained] [-v|--verbosity] [--version-suffix]
dotnet publish [-h|--help]
```

Comment: Currently only publishing to Azure is supported by Visual Studio for Mac. There are plans to support publishing to other locations similar to what Visual Studio on Windows supports.